# Transform hand written loop to std library call

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have recently watched the talk from Sean Parent about C++ seasoning from 2013. If I understood him right, he says that you can eliminate almost all (all?) hand written loops from your code. My question is how to achieve this? 
Let's consider the following code:

```
class ProgressDialog
{
  //interesting part of that class
  void SetPosition(int position);
  bool IsCancelRequested();
  void SetHeader(const std::string& status);
}
void foo( const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
  ProgressDialog dlg;
  long position = 0;
  for( const auto& s : v)
  {
    ++position;
    dlg.SetPosition(position);
    dlg.SetHeader("Processing"+ s);
    DoSomethingThatTakesSomeTime(s);
    if(dlg.IsCancelRequested()) break;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to refactor away the hand written loop?

Comment: Would you accept `std::for_each`? :P

Comment: Sean's advice should not be taken to such extremes.... Even though quite a few raw loops re-implement standard algorithms, not *all of them* do.

Comment: There *is* an algorithm here - "do a thing up until some element matching a condition is found". Come up with a good name for that abstraction, then make it a separate function in your code. The Standard Library does not attempt to provide every possible algorithm, but give commonly useful ones and good examples of how to create your own. Perhaps it would look like `Iter do_until(Iter first, Iter last, Func action, Pred predicate)`, where `Iter`, `Func`, and `Pred` are template parameters.

Comment: Try to favour clarity in your code. It'll be a lot easier for anyone or even yourself to understand when you revisit your code after a period of time. You can replace that modern c++ for-loop (auto &&i : v), with a normal for-loop (std::size_t i=0; ..etc..). That way you can avoid declaring the position counter that you have and use the counter from the for-loop. You can use a lambda, but I don't think it's the time and place for it to be used.

Comment: It would probably be a bit more amenable to standard algorithms if you had something like a `ProgressDialogIterator` that has increment and dereference operators but I'm not sure it is worth the effort. The fact that the function contains one loop and nothing else I think you are doing reasonably well.

Comment: I don't know this talk you refer to. Can you please summarize it in a few words? I believe this would make it easier to understand *why* you want to refactor this loop.

Comment: @zett42 I guess this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH6sSOr-yk8) (slides [here](http://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2013-09-11-cpp-seasoning/cpp-seasoning.pdf)).

Comment: @StoryTeller to be *totally pedantic*, every loop is expressible as a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), which is what `std::accumulate` does

Comment: @Caleth - I wasn't trying to be pedantic. I was just paraphrasing a point from Sean Parent's lecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The general case

> If I understood him right, he says that you can eliminate almost all (all?) hand written loops from your code.

Well, yes and no - obviously it depends on what kind of loops you write. He slightly exaggerated, I believe, to emphasize the fact that *many* loops are not really necessary, and may better be refactored into application of standard library "algorithms".

Also, essentially any loop can be replaced with an `std::for_each`, but that doesn't really count since it only hides the explicit loop progression control and is still "just a loop".

#### Your specific example

In your case, the loop iteration does work while logging/reporting each iteration of the work being done, and being willing to accept an abort request. You could consider writing a variant of `std::for_each` with that additional aspect of functionality, then using it for the actual work as a special case, e.g.

```
namespace with_progress_dialog {

template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >
void for_each(
    InputIt          first, 
    InputIt          last,
    UnaryFunction    function,
    std::string_view message_prefix = "Processing item " )
{
    ProgressDialog progress_dialog;
    for (position_t position = 0; first != last; ++first, ++position) 
    {
        progress_dialog.SetPosition(position);
        progress_dialog.SetHeader(message_prefix + position);
        function(*first);
        if ( progress_dialog.IsCancelRequested() ) { break; }
    }
}
}
```

and then call

```
// ... etc. etc. ...
with_progress_dialog::for_each(
    std::begin(v), std::end(v),
    &DoSomethingThatTakesSomeTime);
```

Now, this is somewhat of an over-generalization, for sure. But I'm assuming you have other cases in which you open a progress dialog that gradually updates. So perhaps adapt your generalization accordingly. Or - maybe you can keep some sort of a window-level state when you're doing heavy lifting, and have another thread track that and open a dialog window when necessary, or show an indication on a status bar. Yet another option maybe to have that dialog run in a [co-rountine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=proxLbvHGEQ) (but that's pretty speculative, not sure it's a good idea).

---

Note: It is not a good idea, and potentially unsafe, to just go ahead and print strings you're working on - which can likely originate in inputs you don't control. You need to make sure they're not too long, and consider sanitizing them. In my code I'm only printing the index ("position").

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes, fixed. (You can also edit instead of commenting in these cases).

Comment: Then my comment would have been just *"100% this instead of trying to overgeneralize before needing to"* :P

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this adds any clarity, but it is an attempt to refactor the concept of the loop and early break.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ciso646>

struct ProgressDialog
{
  //interesting part of that class
  void SetPosition(int position);
  bool IsCancelRequested();
  void SetHeader(const std::string& status);
};
void DoSomethingThatTakesSomeTime(std::string const&);

// iterate over a container, calling func with the current value.
// if func returns false, cease iterating immediately.
// return true if terminated early
// note: func must return false if it wishes early termination,
// otherwise true
template<class Cont, class F> 
auto for_each_while(Cont&& container, F&& func)
{
    for(auto&& s : container)
        if (not func(s)) 
            return true;
    return false;
}

void foo( const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    auto update_dialog = 
    [position = 0, dlg = ProgressDialog()](auto&& s) mutable
    {
        ++position;
        dlg.SetPosition(position);
        dlg.SetHeader("Processing"+ s);
        DoSomethingThatTakesSomeTime(s);
        return !dlg.IsCancelRequested();
    };
    for_each_while(v, update_dialog);
}
```

And here is some std library abuse which achieves the same thing.

**I strongly suggest that you do not do this, as it is not clear to the casual reader what is going on!**

```
void foo( const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    int position = 0;
    auto dlg = ProgressDialog();

    std::find_if(begin(v), end(v), 
                 [&](auto&& s)
    {
        ++position;
        dlg.SetPosition(position);
        dlg.SetHeader("Processing"+ s);
        DoSomethingThatTakesSomeTime(s);
        return dlg.IsCancelRequested();
    });
}
```

Comment: @YSC yes, sorry. The old c-hacker still lurks within. I'll fix it.

Comment: What is the problem this solution attempts to solve?

Comment: @zett42 it abstracts out the concept of iterating until some condition fails.

Comment: @zett42 ^^ this. But as mentioned in the answer I am dubious as to whether the abstraction does really add any clarity.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the resulting code is worse than the OPs code. It's always bad to get religious about programming rules, and the "don't use raw loops" rule is no exception. Usually, we should strive to use what's the most clear, simple, robust code. Unless there are other constraints like time and memory consumption that need to be taken into account... No rule without exception!